# "This facility has/have a new administrator"

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

"This facility has a new administrator" — is this correct? Or should it be "this facility have a new administrator"?

Comment: *Has* is a singular verb; *this facility* is a singular noun.  Pair 'em up.

Comment: A simple grammar stuff.

    The correct one should strongly be "This facility has a new administrator."

Why ?

    Because the word "facility" is singular, and we relate it to 'The third-person singular' which is in this situation 'It' (It's the facility).

    So according to the conjugation of the verb "To have", the third-person singular of have is "It has". That why we should say : This facility (=It) has (=TPS of have) a new administrator.

TPS = The third-person singular.

Comment: Though _logical concord_ (eg 'The team are fighting amongst themselves') is acceptable to many people, 'facility' does not really lend itself to this type of agreement. Though it can be used as a collective noun (_facility_ (Military) an **organization** or building offering supporting capability)(Collins). Using the singular determiner 'this' really settles the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

"This facility has a new administrator" is the correct one.  Facility is an 'it', so it follows the verb form that is applied to he, she, and it.
If it was a plural, I, you, or they, it would be "They/I/You have a new administrator".

Comment: 'The jury have a new foreman' is quite acceptable, at least in BrE. But one could say ' "jury" is an "it" '.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth 'Jury' is a collective noun, which can be treated as plural or singular.  It is more common in British English to treat collective nouns as plural, such as in your example.  In American English the singular form is more common.